# Force a clear cache

Tags: javascript, caching

I realised that sometimes my browser wont load the newest script when refreshing a page. Is there a solution to it? Something like a forced refresh of the ressources(html, js) being used?

Oh and by the way: is there a shortcut in js to set marked text as a comment(//, /* */)(using the sublime editor)?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, questions need to be limited in scope. So please only ask one question at a time. If you'd like to ask a question about Sublime, do some research and see if anyone has already answered it. If not, feel free to ask another question here. Read the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for information on how to write a good question.

Comment: @Mike C Alright, thank you :)